# Android emulator Wi-Fi

Tags: android, emulation, wifi

Is it possible to connect the emulator to Wi-fi? Since am not using eclipse or any IDE... Am trying to connect a stand alone emulator to Wi-fi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, while you can use your computer's Internet connection in the emulator, it's not reliable to use it for simulating Wi-Fi. The [**WifiManager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) gets confused when you switch/want to test your connectivity state.

Even in Android 1.5, there were some problems with it [**(Issue 2571 - android)**](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2571), and while you can use your Internet for simulating HTTP connections and downloading data, finer control over Wi-Fi connectivity should better be done with a device.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the emulator should connect to the internet via your PC/MAC then it works without any changes.

I am able to browser the internet via the browser in the emulator i.e. the emulator has internet connectivity.